# JavaFX - Nodes Whiting Out

Tags: javafx, textfield

Hi I have quite an unusual query. I have made a small JavaFX program and am very proud of the results. However I recently noticed a bug I can't seem to rap my head around. I can't recreate it either and do not have a screen shot of it unfortunately. However you can see a screenshot of the general program below in the state that triggered the problems.

I was running my program like normal and gave it quite a large load to handle (a lot of gradients as seen below). Then what happened was that in any TextField I typed in all edited text became a completely white rectangle and if I tried to update the image preview to  the right it also turned white. If I let the program be in this white state for about ten seconds everything would load back in and behave like normal until I went to edit anything again.

It happened with any StyleSheet I loaded and as mentioned I cannot seem to recreate it. So my question is this. Is this a known error that can occur if you configure your scene in the wrong way (or something similar) or have I just managed to screw things up in general? The source code is quite long and I have absolutely no Idea where the problem may lie so I won't post any if you don't feel like a specific part may be interesting.

I am also aware that this type of general question is not really liked here so sorry about that. If you can suggest another more suitable forum I would be more than happy to move my question there.

//Thanks for any help.

[image]

EDIT: I finally managed to get a screen shot of the bug. I am not having high hopes that anyone is going to answer this though...

[image]

Comment: So the problem is that white rectangles in the screen shot?

Comment: Exactly, when I try to interact with any node it is replaced with a white rectangle. It still works as expected but it does not give any visual ques as to what is happening.

Comment: This is happening to me too. Any news? Any info?

Comment: @user3804769 No, I still have no solution for this unfortunately. Please post here if you manage to solve it.

Comment: Further examination led me to believe that there were unmanaged exceptions I didn't see in the logs. In my case they were caused by unsynchronized threads.